# CGContextSetShadowWithColor not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

This code should be showing a shadow, but it isn't:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//Border
CGMutablePathRef outerPath = createRoundedRectForRect(self.bounds, MENU_BUTTON_OUTER_RADIUS);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.18] CGColor]);
CGContextAddPath(context, outerPath);
CGContextFillPath(context);

//Button

UIColor *buttonColor;
if (self.type == JMenuButtonTypeBlack) {
    buttonColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1.0];
}
else if (self.type == JMenuButtonTypeWhite) {
    buttonColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.72 alpha:1.0];
}

CGRect insideRect = rectForRectWithInset(self.bounds, 3);

CGMutablePathRef innerPath = createRoundedRectForRect(insideRect, MENU_BUTTON_INNER_RADIUS);
CGPoint gradientTop = CGPointMake(0, insideRect.origin.y);
CGPoint gradientBottom = CGPointMake(0, insideRect.origin.y + insideRect.size.height);

//Base color
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [buttonColor CGColor]);
CGContextAddPath(context, innerPath);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

//Gradient 1
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGFloat colors [] = { 
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.16, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.11
};

CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);

CGContextAddPath(context, innerPath);
CGContextClip(context);

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, gradientTop, gradientBottom, 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

CGContextRestoreGState(context);


//Shadow
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddPath(context, innerPath);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 2), 3.0, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

This is what it looks like so far. The shadow code doesn't make a difference:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not drawing anything after you set the shadow. You need to either stroke or fill (`CGContextStrokePath()` or `CGContextFillPath()`) the path in order for it to be drawn into the context and thus appear on screen.